# Is cohomology "bad"?

Tags: soft-question, homology-cohomology, orientation

I think this is a simple question, I hope it is not too soft. I used to think that the smaller the cohomology of an object is, the better it is behaved. For instance, the degree to which the existence and uniqueness of a global primitive of differentials forms on a smooth manifold  that have local primitives fail is controlled by the (de Rham) cohomology, the failure of an exact sequence $0 \to A \to K \to G \to 0$ of groups to be split is controlled (under suitable hypotheses) by the group cohomology $H(G,A)$, etc. And more generally there are many invariants whose non-triviality is correlated (as far as I know) both to the cohomology being non-trivial and the object being complicated, like the Galois group, the fundamental group or the $K$-theory rings.

Isn't it paradoxical then that orientability, which seems to me a good property to have, is equivalent (for compact topological manifolds without boundary) to having non-zero top-degree (singular integral) cohomology?

Comment: Seeing the title of this thread, "Is cohomology good?"  I was going to answer "NO!  I've taken a course in cohomology and it is not good, it is wicked and evil!!"  But apparently that is not the kind of answer you want!

Comment: Small comment: It's not good if too much cohomology vanishes. In the end we might want to distinguish objects using their cohomology and if too much of it vanishes, the cohomology theory becomes useless.

Comment: It is true that many homology and cohomology theories can be thought to measure how far an object is from some kind of "ideal" object. It's not the only way to think about it, but it's not wrong. In algebraic topology, the "ideal object" might be contractible spaces. Hochschild homology measures how far an algebra over a ring is from being a polynomial algebra.

Comment: @PaulK Talking from my small experience: we want to distinguish them because they are different; if all the cohomology vanished it would be even better because they'd already be classified, all being trivial.

Comment: Often cohomology represents "obstacles" (so indeed something "bad"). Orientability can in fact be viewed as an obstacle - it *prevents* that you can move an object around and threby swap its chirality

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So for an object not to have any cohomology doesn't mean that everything that we want is true, but rather that everything is true, including things that we don't want. thanks a lot.